# How can i make this binary to decimal code to recursion

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

Can anybody know how to make this code into recursion in javascript? i want to make a code that converts binary to decimal but uses recursion in javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Converting Binary to Decimal</title>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="binary" />
        <input type="submit" value="convert" onclick="convertBinary()" />
    </div>
    <script>
        function convertBinary()
        {
            var binaryNumber = document.getElementById('binary').value;
            binaryNumber = parseInt(binaryNumber,2);
            var decimalNumber = binaryNumber.toString(10);
            alert(decimalNumber)
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use recursion here. Are you interested in <s>reinventing the wheel</s> implementing `parseInt` and `toString` yourself? You can use recursion for those if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

What i did is a sort of character manipulation, but this will work dynamically and has also some sort of recursion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <h4>Enter a binary value to convert into a decimal value.</h4>
            Binary number : <input type="number" id="num1" onkeyup="bintodec(num1.value)"><br/><br/>
            Result:<br/><br/>
            <div id="res"></div> 
        </form>                                                     
    <div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tmp =0; 
function bintodec(b){
    len = b.length-1;
    if(b.charAt(0)==0||b.charAt(0)==1){
        if(b.charAt(0) == "1" && b != ""){
            tmp = tmp + Math.pow(2,len);
        }
        display(b);
    }
    else{
        tmp="Input may only contain ones and zeroes.";
        display("");
    }
}
function display(bn){
    if(bn.slice(1) == ""){
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=tmp;
        tmp = 0;
    }
    else{
        bn = bn.slice(1);
        bintodec(bn);
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```